# has_many through multi conditional association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have customers and writers and stories.

A published writer is an association between a customer and writer through stories where the story is accepted. I can just do a uniq on writer id to get the published writers for the customer.

The code looks like:

`has_many :accepted_stories, -> { accepted }, class_name: Story`

`has_many :published_writers, ->{ uniq(:writer_id) }, through: :accepted_stories, source: :writer, class_name: Writer`

Now I want to just get the published writers who have high approval ratings. This means writers who have at least 50% of the stories for that customer accepted since a customer can also reject a story.

So I am trying to write something like what's below, but I'm not sure how.

`has_many :accepted_or_rejected_stories, -> { rejected || accepted }, class_name: Story`

`has_many :published_writers_with_high_approval, ->{ where sum accepted stories are >= sum rejected stories }, through: :accepted_or_rejected_stories, source: :writer, class_name: Writer`